# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^2+4 x+5} \mathrm{~d} x$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

The questions itself is pretty straightforward. I want to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^2+4 x+5} \mathrm{~d} x$ where $x$ is taking complex values and this basically is a complex improper integral.

I actually know how to solve this question and below is the solution:

> Note that $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^2+4 x+5} \mathrm{~d} x=\operatorname{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i x}}{x^2+4 x+5} \mathrm{~d} x\right)
> $$
> Consider the function
> $$
> f(z)=\frac{e^{i z}}{z^2+4 z+5}
> $$
> which has two simple poles at $-2 \pm i$. We let $R>0$ and we consider the curves
> $$
> s_{-R, R}(t)=t, t \in[-R, R] \text {, and } C_R(t)=R e^{i t}, t \in[0, \pi] .
> $$
> Note that $\gamma_R=s_{-R, R} \wedge C_R$ is a positively oriented semicircle. By the Residue Theorem, since only $-2+i$ lies on the upper half plane, for $R$ large enough we get
> $$
> \int_{\gamma_R} f(z) \mathrm{d} z=\int_{s_{-R, R}} f(z) \mathrm{d} z+\int_{C_R} f(z) \mathrm{d} z=2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}(f(z) ;-2+i)=\frac{\pi}{e} e^{-2 i} .
> $$
> We have that
> $$
> \int_{s_{-R, R}} f(z) \mathrm{d} z=\int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{i x}}{x^2+4 x+5} \mathrm{~d} x
> $$
> and, since for large $R$,
> $$
> \left|z^2+4 z+5\right|=|z|^2\left|1+4 / z+5 / z^2\right| \geq|z|^2 / 2,
> $$
> we obtain the following upper bound (for large $R$ )
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \left|\int_{C_R} \frac{e^{i z}}{z^2+4 z+5} \mathrm{~d} z\right| & =\pi R \max _{z \in C_R^*} \frac{\left|e^{i(\operatorname{Re} z+i \operatorname{Im} z)}\right|}{\left|z^2+4 z+5\right|} \\
> & \leq 2 \pi R \max _{\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|=R \wedge \operatorname{Im} z \geq 0\}} \frac{e^{-\operatorname{Im} z}}{|z|^2} \\
> & \leq \frac{2 \pi R}{R^2} .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Hence,
> $$
> \lim _{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{C_R} f(z) \mathrm{d} z=0 .
> $$
> Therefore,
> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i x}}{x^2+4 x+5} \mathrm{~d} x=\lim _{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{i x}}{x^2+4 x+5} \mathrm{~d} x=\frac{\pi}{e}(\cos 2-i \sin 2),
> $$
> and consequently
> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^2+4 x+5} \mathrm{~d} x=-\frac{\pi}{e} \sin 2
> $$

and this gives us the value of that integral.

However, before starting all these calculations, we should prove that integrated is convergent and then we're allowed to calculate the integral. But I don't really know how to show the convergence of this integral. So what I was trying to do is that using IBP, we have:
$$\int_{-R}^R \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+4x+5}dx= \frac{-\cos(x)}{x^2+4x+5}-\int_{-R}^R\frac{-\cos(x)(2x+4)}{(x^2+4x+5)^2}dx$$
Now, for sufficiently large enough $R$, $\frac{-\cos(x)}{x^2+4x+5}$ is obviously going to zero because $-1\leq \cos(x) \leq 1$, while the denominator goes to infinity and a similar argument works for the other function as $\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{(2x+4)}{(x^2+4x+5)^2}=0$ but I'm not sure if my reasoning is valid, especially if I want to write this in a preliminary exam.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious,$$\int_a^b \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2+4x+5}\,dx \le \int_a^b \frac{|\sin(x)|}{x^2+4x+5} \, dx \le \int_a^b \frac1{(x+2)^2+1} \, dx<\infty$$

Comment: @user170231Hmm, I think I was missing something so obvious. Thanks a lot.